# What is a Neural attention model and how can it be used for text summarization?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing

We are doing a research on multi-document (one document max 100 words) text summarization. We are looking into abstractive text summarization methods. I need following things to be clarified.

1. Please explain what exactly in **Neural attention model.**
2. How can the Neural attention model be used for **abstractive text summarization?**

Comment: You are asking a very broad question whose only answer is "read the papers about it". Do you have any specific question about this model?

Comment: Here is the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.00685.pdf.

Comment: I have already read this paper and I am still not clear on what Neural attention model is. In this paper they have only mentioned that they are using local attention.